# Inno Setup DefaultDirName coming up with Downloads inserted

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup script for installing my VB.NET program.  I want to install my program in the `My Documents` folder.  `My Documents` is my destination folder.  In my Inno Setup script I have the following:

```
DefaultDirName=My Documents\{#MyAppName}
```

During the installation, for the destination folder, instead of coming up as

```
C:\Users\Rick\My Documents
```

it comes up as

```
C:\Users\Rick\Downloads\My Documents
```

Note `Downloads` is inserted before `My Documents`.

If I manually delete `Downloads`, it goes where I want. How can I change it so `Downloads` doesn't come up as part of the destination folder?  I'm sure it has to do with the install .exe being in the `Downloads` folder.  That's where it goes when it is downloaded.  But I don't know how to fix it so `Downloads` doesn't appear as part of the destination file path. Can you help?  I am not so good with the Inno Setup language so it's probably something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultDirName` should be an absolute path.

You are using a relative path. In that case the path is resolved relatively to installer startup directory (what would be `C:\Users\Rick\Downloads`).

Use an absolute path and do not hard-code the `My Documents` name. You want this:

```
DefaultDirName={userdocs}\{#MyAppName}
```

See [Inno Setup constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts).